# Why flutter add title on status bar?

Tags: flutter

[image: the title overflowed]

My page don't need appbar and need load a list from api and list it with title.The title should in the head of listView not the status bar.

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: null,
      body: Column(children: [
        ListTile(
          title: Text("chose your credentials",
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodySmall),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: ListView(
// _credentials is a list load from api
            children: List.generate(_credentials.length, (index) {
              return Card(
                child: ListTile(
                  title: Text(_credentials[index].title),
                  trailing: Icon(Icons.star),
                ),
              );
            }),
          ),
        ),
      ]),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        child: const Text('ok'),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make sure your title is below the status bar you can use [`SafeArea`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SafeArea-class.html).

Wrap your body with the widget:

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: // ... Your body
      ),
    );
}
```

If you were using the parameter `appBar` from `Scaffold`, the `Scaffold` would automatically put a `SafeArea` on top of your screen. But since you are not using it, it doesn't do it so you'll have to add it manually.

Answer (score 1):

wrap your body with `SafeArea`. this will indent the child by enough to avoid the status bar at the top of the screen.

It will also indent the child by the amount necessary to avoid The Notch on the iPhone X, or other similar creative physical features of the display.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Contianer() //app's body
      ),
    );
}
```

and using `AppBar` can also fix this problem, it would put a `SafeArea` automatically

Answer (score 0):

```
Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    brightness: Brightness.dark,
    title: null,
  ),
  body: Column(
    children: [
      ListTile(
        title: Text(
          "Choose your credentials",
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodySmall,
        ),
      ),
      Expanded(
        child: ListView(
          children: List.generate(_credentials.length, (index) {
            return Card(
              child: ListTile(
                title: Text(_credentials[index].title),
                trailing: Icon(Icons.star),
              ),
            );
          }),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
  floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
    onPressed: () {},
    child: const Text('ok'),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply wrap the `Scaffold` with `SafeArea` Widget. SafeArea widget prevents the child widget from going after the appbar or bottombar.

Example:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: // ... Your body
      ),
    );
}
```